# Matlab: How to Exclude Zero from Domain?

Tags: matlab, math-software

I want to plot the **wireframe surface** of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ in Matlab. The code I typed is as follows.

> x=-0.1:.001:0.1;
>   y=-0.1:.001:0.1;
>   [X,Y]= meshgrid(x,y);
>   Z=((X.^2)-(Y.^2))/((X.^2)+(Y.^2));
>   mesh(Z)

However, an empty graph appears, and a line says:

> Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.

I know this happens because the graph is not defined at $x=0$, $y=0$. Is there any way that I can change the domain of $x$ and $y$ so that it excludes $0$?

I did plot the **solid surface** with the following code, which works.

> clear
>   syms x y
>   ezsurf(((x.^2)-(y.^2))/((x.^2)+(y.^2)))

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You want the divide to be elementwise. i.e. ./. The effect of this will be one element equal to inf corresponding to the (0,0) element.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=-0.1:.001:0.1;
y=-0.1:.001:0.1;

% Add these lines
x = x(x~=0);
y = y(y~=0);

[X,Y]= meshgrid(x,y);
Z=((X.^2)-(Y.^2))/((X.^2)+(Y.^2));
mesh(Z)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, and it still produces an empty graph and the same line: 'Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.'

Comment: @euler It's because of the /.

Comment: Ah yes, add a `/.` Missed that!